# Parsing webpage link returns "You are being redirected..."

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to parse all links from the following site https://consolecrunch.com/ using jsoup

```
    public void GetLinks(final String p0)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    try
                    {
                        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(p0).get();
                        String title = doc.title();
                        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

                        builder.append(title).append("\n");

                        for (Element link : links)
                        {
                            Log.d("LINK", builder.append("\n").append("Link : ").append(link.attr("href"))
                                  .append("\n").append("Text : ").append(link.text()).toString());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.d("EXCEPTION", e.toString());
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                result.setText(builder.toString());
                            }
                        });
                }

            }).start();
    }
}
```

It always returns "You are being redirected..."
How can I get past the redirect?
I have tried 
followredirects(true)
And
followredirects(false)

Comment: I can't reproduce problem with redirection. For me it returns status 403 which suggests forbidden resource because I didn't send enough info to get access to that resource like user-agent header representing browser.

Comment: @Pshemo When I do it it gives me this text in my textview "you are being redirected" instead of displaying the hrefs from the webpage, it works when I try Google for the url

Comment: Use a webview to render with js support.